# linq get inner attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

what im trying to do is, i have the following xml:

> Postcode id="E20 2AP" from="test1" to="test2"/>

im trying to search for the postcode id and then get the from and to text from that id the code i have:

```
    Public Shared Function GetFromDate(ByVal PostCode As String) As String
    Dim LoadToAddresses = From ex In doc.Descendants.Elements("Postcode") Select New With {.accountName = ex.Attribute("id").Value, .datefrom = ex.Attribute("from").Value}
    For Each x In LoadToAddresses
        Dim datefrom = (From p In LoadToAddresses Where p.accountName = PostCode Select New With {.datefrom = p.datefrom}).Single
        Return datefrom.ToString
    Next
End Function
```

this works but it returns:

> { datefrom = test }

i just want it to state "test"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Return datefrom.ToString
Return datefrom.datefrom
```

or:

```
'Dim datefrom = (From p In LoadToAddresses Where p.accountName = PostCode Select New With {.datefrom = p.datefrom}).Single
Dim datefrom = (From p In LoadToAddresses Where p.accountName = PostCode Select p.datefrom}).Single
```